# Laravel White Index Of/ Page error

Tags: php, laravel, server

I have just uploaded a laravel project from development server to live server direct into the /public_html folder

copied it over like for like and now when i go to the website it brings up a white page which shows the folder structure - index of/ - and not the website

what do i need to change to fix this issue?

Comment: that doesn't work like that...maybe with .htaccess file you could redirect it but anyway you need to learn some things before you deploy a laravel app

Comment: Did you upload vendor folder too?

Comment: @lewis4u why not give me some help then...

Comment: @buglinjo yes uploaded all files and then vendor folder

Comment: here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gD53Qz3vSrU - watch those 4 videos and learn

Comment: actually this one is for you because you have a shared hosting https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQMZld0Iroo

Comment: if I understand correctly, the server's public_html folder is where public files are listed which can be assets, static pages, or files. I would rather that you set_up your configuration file for example if you are using `apache`, to point to laravel's public directory so it could render your project correctly.

Comment: I recomend this guide to deploy a laravel app to a shared hosting: https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e#.3petu89kg

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ssh access to your account in shared hosting you could do something like this:

1. Upload the project outside the `public_html`.
2. Symlink the `public_html` with `public` directory of laravel.

You might have the directory structure like this in your hosting account:

```
|-your-account
    |-public_html
        |-index.html
```

You need to make it like this:

```
|-your-account
    |-project-directory
        |-public
        |-vendor
        |-....   
    |-public_html
        |-index.html
```

Now, you could delete the `public_html` using:

```
rm -rf ~/public_html
```

Then create the symlink to the `public_html` using:

```
ln -s /home/your-account/project-directory/public /home/your-account/public_html
```

**where:**

your-acccount = your shared hosting account name

project-directory = your laravel project directory

If you are using `cPanel` and don't have ssh access, you could try running the command in Cron Job like:

> https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/cron_jobs.htm
>
> https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

If there is some error on storage permission you might need to recreate the folder inside the `storage/framework` and give it the permission of `755`.

Hope it suits your need.